# Set the path of Google Binary on Webdriverio+Selenium

Tags: selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

How can I set the path of the Google Binary on the stack Webdriverio+Selenium+GoogleDriver? It expects the binary on `/usr/bin/google-chrome` but since I am using Heroku I cannot write the Google binary on that folder.

Comment: You meant ChromeDriver, not GoogleDriver.

You can add CHROME_BIN env variable and set chrome there in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the binary path in your capabilities:

```
var client = require('webdriverio').remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            binary: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the chromedriver executable by providing the following argument when running the java server standalone:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\PATH-TO-CHROMEDRIVER\chromedriver.exe"
```